# Video path in Android 11

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gallery, android-11

Please let me know, how can I get **full path of selected video from Gallery** in **Android 11**. I can get path till **Android version 10**. But am stuck in **Android 11**.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 11 (R) file path access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360368/android-11-r-file-path-access)

Comment: You should not try to get a file system path from a nice uri. You can use the uri directly to do with the selected file what you want.